# Create a new column based on conditional inclusion fulfilling conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, exclusion-constraint

**My dataset looks like this:**

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","345","5","345","567","79"), sex = c(Female, Female, Female, Male, Male, Male)
                 waist = c(60, 89, 90, 110, 200, 150),  tryglicerides = c(100, 150, 170, 105, 200, 140),HDL = c(50, 41, 20, 37, 30, 40), hypertension = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), diabetes = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Could you help me coding this in R please?

Thanks!

I need to create a new column that will be called `METABOLIC_SYNDROME`. For the participant to be `TRUE` in the column `METABOLIC_SYNDROME` needs to fulfil 3/5 of these conditions:

- *Waist:* ≥89 in Female, ≥102 in Male
- *Trygliceride*: ≥150
- *HDL*: ≤40 Male, ≤50 Female
- *Hypertension*: TRUE
- *Diabetes*: TRUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sum 5 boolean expressions covering all your requirements:

```r
waist <- (df$sex == 'Female' & df$Waist >= 89) | (df$sex == 'Male' & df$Waist >= 102)
trygliceride <- df$tryglicerides >= 150
hdl <- (df$sex == 'Female' & df$HDL <= 50) | (df$sex == 'Male' & df$HDL <= 40)
hypertension <- df$hypertension
diabetes <- df$diabetes

df$METABOLIC_SYNDROME <- waist + trygliceride + hdl + hypertension + diabetes >= 3
```